# How to speed up linq query C#

Tags: c#, linq

My linq query takes 30 seconds - 60 seconds to execute.

How do I write it to work faster?

```
  var result = (from Produkt in _dbContext.Produkt.AsNoTracking()
                      join ProdlagerT in _dbContext.ProdlagerT.AsNoTracking() on new { X1 = Produkt.Nummer, X2 = Produkt.Lagerplacering } equals new { X1 = ProdlagerT.Produktnr, X2 = ProdlagerT.Lagerplats } into gj
                      from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join Ordrad in _dbContext.Ordrad.AsNoTracking() on Produkt.Nummer equals Ordrad.Produktnr
                      select new PlacesToFill
                      {
                          amount = subpet.Lagersaldo,
                          description = Produkt.Benämning,
                          prodNmbr = Produkt.Nummer,
                          place = Produkt.Lagerplacering
                      }).ToList();// tog bort Distinct


        result = result.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Since no one knows your database it's impossible to see where you have missing indexes for example. Use the sql-profiler. In your code there is one thing, why you use `Distinct` on the created list instead of in the database? So change it to: `}).Distinct().ToList();// tog bort Distinct`

Comment: If you configure your logs to show debug traces, EFCore should be outputtng the corresponding query, you should be able to use that on the query perfomance analyzer in MSSQL SSMS and see what is the most time consuming operation

Comment: Look at the generated SQL. Execute it in SSMS(if you're using that). Look at the "Actual Execution Plan"(Ctrl+M) in SSMS to see what part of your query takes the longest. SSMS will also suggest missing indexes that could speed up the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users said, it may depend from your database structure. A little improvement should be something like this:

```
var result = (from Produkt in _dbContext.Produkt.AsNoTracking()
              join ProdlagerT in _dbContext.ProdlagerT.AsNoTracking() on new { X1 = Produkt.Nummer, X2 = Produkt.Lagerplacering } equals new { X1 = ProdlagerT.Produktnr, X2 = ProdlagerT.Lagerplats } into gj
              from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join Ordrad in _dbContext.Ordrad.AsNoTracking() on Produkt.Nummer equals Ordrad.Produktnr
              select new PlacesToFill
                  {
                      amount = subpet.Lagersaldo,
                      description = Produkt.Benämning,
                      prodNmbr = Produkt.Nummer,
                      place = Produkt.Lagerplacering
                  });

// here you can see the query
var listResult = result.Distinct().ToList();
```

By removing `ToList()` in first query, you should save some time.
You can try to save more time analyzing these points:

- How many rows are you asking for?
- Are you querying on db tables or views?
- Do you have alternatives to Distinct using?